WebStorm thinks ngOnInit is unused function
I am using WebStorm 2024.3 and the IDE suddenly started telling me that ngOnInit and other lifecycle functions are unused methods. Has anyone stumbled on this issue?
I have tried invalidating caches, downgrading, re-upgrading, pulling the project again from scratch etc. Nothing seems to have worked.


Is it only that component, or all components/services?

Could you try installing/updating the Angular Plugin which might be taking care of the suppression of the error in Webstorm for angular code.
The plugin might not be installed, removed recently, out of date or disabled due to some reason.
